# .NET Core UserManager CreateAsync leaves UserName/Email/PhoneNumber always null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

NET Core application implementing a custom `IdentutyUser` logic for some extra fields.

I have managed to create a user using `CreateAsync` but the fields `UserName`, `Email` and `PhoneNumber` are always ignored. The normalized version of them (`NormalizedUserName`, `NormalizedEmail` and `NormalizedPhoneNumber` (the last one was created by me as any non-nullable value is required to be unique)) are created successful but always capitalized.

The Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Registration")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserRegistration(ApplicationUserModel model)
{
    var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = model.UserName,
        Email = model.Email,
        PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        // Other fields that are being inserted normally...
    };

    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, model.Password);

    try
    {
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

If it helps the problematic fields are being overriden by a `ApplicationUser` model class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column("UserName", TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UN_REQUIRED")]
    [StringLength(24, ErrorMessage = "UN_LENGTH", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9-_])+(?:[_-]\w+)?$", ErrorMessage = "UN_INVALID")]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column("Email", TypeName = "nvarchar(64)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EM_REQUIRED")]
    [StringLength(64, ErrorMessage = "EM_LENGTH", MinimumLength = 13)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "EM_INVALID")]
    public override string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("PhoneNumber", TypeName = "nvarchar(15)")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "PN_INVALID")]
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I also have this code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
});
```

What do I have to do to insert the corresponding values into the db along with the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the custom properties , you should use the new `ApplicationUser` in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And `ApplicationDbContext` :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

And confirm that you inject the UserManager with new ApplicationUser in controller:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

At last `Add-migration xx`, `update-database` to let ef to create columns in `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed I don't know how to thank you but I really want to I can finally move on! All I had to do is replace `AddEntityFrameworks<AuthenticationContext>` with your solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have the same problem, and i compared my code with this one and it's the same but I'm still getting NormalizedEmail null in my database while other columns like UserName got Normalized. Any ideas? Thank you in advance